# Unable to click on icons in React Native Modal even with zIndex

Tags: react-native

I have a problem where the two materialicons / touchables in the view can't be clicked. (refer to the code section with the View and zIndex.
I may just be nesting the views wrongly.

- When i add a zIndex, it fixes for IOS, but dosen't work for Android.
- When i remove the ZIndex, it fixes for Android but dosen't work for IOS.
- When i remove the whole  it works on both, but i lose the
  ability to do the space-between as i want to put the icons on the
  opposite end of the row.

Would love some advice on why this is the case. Thank you.

```
     <Modal
          visible={props.showFilter}
          backdropOpacity={0.3}
          transparent={true}
          animationType={'slide'}
        >
    
        <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center'}}>
    
                <View style={{
                  backgroundColor:'white',
                  width: wp('100%'),
                  height: hp('80%')}}>
    
                          >>>    <View style={{zIndex:10, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                                  <TouchableOpacity
                                  onPress={()=> props.close()}
                                  style={{ zIndex:10, paddingHorizontal: 10,top: hp('5%') }} >
                                    <MaterialIcon
                                      name="close"
                                      size={30}
                                      color="#828282"
                                    />
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
    
                                  <TouchableOpacity
                                  onPress={()=> props.showHelp(true)}
                                  style={{ zIndex:10, paddingHorizontal: 10,top: hp('5%') }} >
                                    <MaterialIcon
                                      name="help"
                                      size={30}
                                      color="#828282"
                                    />
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
                              </View>
    
                              <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center', paddingTop: 40,}}>
    
                                    <Text style ={{  fontSize:wp('3.5%'),
                                      fontFamily: 'Gilroy-Bold',
                                      color: '#4F4F4F',
                                      marginBottom: hp("2%"),}}>Filter</Text>
        
                             </View>
    
                </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a crash course on flex and solved it using good flex skills then relying on Z-Index

https://medium.com/@ManningBooks/in-depth-styling-with-react-native-and-flexbox-ee1bda2c5b24

```
  <View style={{flex:1}}>

        <View style ={{ flex: 1,  flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>

        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=> props.show(false)}
        style={{ flex:1, paddingHorizontal: 10,top: hp('5%') }} >
          <MaterialIcon
            name="close"
            size={30}
            color="#828282"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>



        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=> console.log("onpress")}
        style={{ flex:0, paddingHorizontal: 10,top: hp('5%') }} >
          <Text
          style ={{
            color:  "#828282",
            fontFamily: 'Gilroy-Regular',
            textDecorationLine: 'underline',
            fontSize:wp('3.5%')}}> Refresh  </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>

      <View style ={{flex:8, alignItems: 'center'}}>

        <Text style ={{  fontSize:wp('3.5%'),
          fontFamily: 'Gilroy-Bold',
          color: '#4F4F4F',
          marginBottom: hp("2%"),}}>Filter Tags</Text>

        <Text style={{
            marginBottom: hp("2%"),
            color:  "#828282",
            fontFamily: 'Gilroy-Regular',
            fontSize:wp('3.5%'),
            width: '80%'
            }}>

           text

          </Text>

     
      </View>
  </View>
```